# Is there a major pitfall in using a git tag to represent what's in production?

Tags: git

For sure we should have some representation of what's currently in production, but is there some pitfall for using a git tag as that only representation as opposed to a branch?

One can just as easily branch off of a tag to create a new branch if you needed to make a change to what's in production without pulling in changes from a development branch, no?

Comment: The key differences between a tag name and a branch name are: (1) the tag name is expected to name one particular commit *forever* but the branch name is expected to name the *latest* commit, which changes (becomes later) over time; (2) tag names can use a so-called *annotated tag* which adds extra information, such as a cryptographic signature to say "this version is officially approved". Branch names lack the extra annotation data.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no pitfall of using a tag instead of a branch for this.  You can safely do it, and many people do.